# Mocking imgur API calls in Jest unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs

How do I write a test for the upload and delete methods below which returns a mocked value?

```
@Injectable()
export class ImgurService {
  private readonly IMGUR_API_URL = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image';
  private readonly IMGUR_CLIENT_ID = 'Client-ID';
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
 
  upload(upload: string | File, type = 'base64'): Observable<ImgurResponse> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `${this.IMGUR_CLIENT_ID}`);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', upload);
    formData.append('name', UtilService.generateRandomString(32));
    formData.append('type', type);
    return this.http.post<ImgurResponse>(`${this.IMGUR_API_URL}`, formData, {
      headers,
    });
  }
 
  delete(id: string): Observable<ImgurResponse> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `${this.IMGUR_CLIENT_ID}`);
    return this.http.delete<ImgurResponse>(`${this.IMGUR_API_URL}/${id}`, { headers });
  }
}
```

Here is my test logic so far, so far, it runs as expected:

```
import { ImgurService } from './imgur.service';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { ImgurResponse } from '../models/imgur';

describe('ImgurService', () => {
  let service: ImgurService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ImgurService],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ImgurService);
  });

  describe('upload()', () => {
    it('should upload file', () => {
      const mockImgurResponse: ImgurResponse = {
        data: {
          id: 'orunSTu',
          title: null,
          description: null,
          datetime: 1587998106,
          type: 'image/png',
          animated: false,
          width: 2100,
          height: 1709,
          size: 138557,
          views: 0,
          bandwidth: 0,
          vote: null,
          favorite: false,
          nsfw: null,
          section: null,
          account_url: null,
          account_id: 0,
          is_ad: false,
          in_most_viral: false,
          tags: [],
          ad_type: 0,
          ad_url: '',
          in_gallery: false,
          deletehash: 'N9YaI4CIkq3rIar',
          name: 'Hero Image',
          link: 'https://i.imgur.com/keznKEA.png',
        },
        success: true,
        status: 200,
      };
      jest.spyOn(service, 'upload').mockReturnValue(of(mockImgurResponse));
      expect(service.upload('test')).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

However, my test coverage is woefully low:

```
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
 imgur.service.ts |   52.94 |        0 |   33.33 |   46.67 | 15-27             
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: It shouldn't be surprising your test coverage is low; the actual implementation _isn't involved in the test_. Don't mock out the thing you're supposed to be testing. You might find a TDD workflow makes it more obvious when you're making this mistake, because the test passing before you've actually written the method gives it away a bit.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll have a look again.

Comment: Managed to figure out using HTTP Requests Mock.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by intercepting the requests and overriding any calls with our mock data. In the example below, if Imgur's API is hit, we want to answer with the mock data we have defined earlier to test our service.

```
import { ImgurService } from './imgur.service';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ImgurResponse } from '../models/imgur';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ImgurServiceInterceptorMock implements HttpInterceptor {
  mockImgurResponse: ImgurResponse = {
    data: {
      id: 'orunSTu',
      title: null,
      description: null,
      datetime: 1587998106,
      type: 'image/png',
      animated: false,
      width: 2100,
      height: 1709,
      size: 138557,
      views: 0,
      bandwidth: 0,
      vote: null,
      favorite: false,
      nsfw: null,
      section: null,
      account_url: null,
      account_id: 0,
      is_ad: false,
      in_most_viral: false,
      tags: [],
      ad_type: 0,
      ad_url: '',
      in_gallery: false,
      deletehash: 'N9YaI4CIkq3rIar',
      name: 'Hero Image',
      link: 'https://i.imgur.com/keznKEA.png',
    },
    success: true,
    status: 200,
  };

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    if (request.method === 'POST') {
      return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: this.mockImgurResponse }));
    }
    if (request.method === 'DELETE') {
      return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: this.mockImgurResponse }));
    }
    next.handle(request);
  }
}

describe('ImgurService', () => {
  let service: ImgurService;
  const mockImgurResponse: ImgurResponse = {
    data: {
      id: 'orunSTu',
      title: null,
      description: null,
      datetime: 1587998106,
      type: 'image/png',
      animated: false,
      width: 2100,
      height: 1709,
      size: 138557,
      views: 0,
      bandwidth: 0,
      vote: null,
      favorite: false,
      nsfw: null,
      section: null,
      account_url: null,
      account_id: 0,
      is_ad: false,
      in_most_viral: false,
      tags: [],
      ad_type: 0,
      ad_url: '',
      in_gallery: false,
      deletehash: 'N9YaI4CIkq3rIar',
      name: 'Hero Image',
      link: 'https://i.imgur.com/keznKEA.png',
    },
    success: true,
    status: 200,
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        ImgurService,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: ImgurServiceInterceptorMock,
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ImgurService);
  });

  describe('upload()', () => {
    it('should upload file', () => {
      expect(
        service.upload('test').subscribe((result) => {
          expect(result).toEqual(mockImgurResponse);
        })
      );
    });
  });

  describe('delete()', () => {
    it('should delete file', () => {
      expect(
        service.delete('test').subscribe((result) => {
          expect(result).toEqual(mockImgurResponse);
        })
      );
    });
  });
});
```